# What is the verb for saying that you are suddenly frightened or afraid?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that expresses that you are suddenly very afraid, frightened because of the actions of someone else. For example,

> Mr. Smith had not expected his children to be inside his room, so when he entered the room and his children jumped on him he ______.

I'm not looking for something like *became afraid* or *became frightened*, because that expresses more long-term afraidness.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To **be startled** would work:

> Mr. Smith had not expected his children to be inside his room, so when he entered the room and they jumped on him he was startled.

From Dictionary.com's entry on [startle](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/startled):

> 1. to disturb or agitate suddenly as by surprise or alarm.
> 2. to cause to start involuntarily, by or as by a sudden shock.

Or to **jump**. One can jump in surprise, see meaning 3 [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/jump):

> to move or jerk suddenly, as from surprise or shock.

Although that wouldn't look too good in your example sentence since the word "jumped" already appears there. I would rephrase it as:

> Mr. Smith had not expected his children to be inside his room, so when he entered the room and they sprang on him he jumped.

Comment: This works for what I'm writing, I was especially looking for "to cause to start involuntarily, by or as by a sudden shock." Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Consider **spook**.  It's often used to describe a horse being suddenly startled, but also can be applied to humans:

> to make frightened or frantic
>   *especially* :  to startle into violent activity ([MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spook))

Here's an example sentence:

> *The news spooked investors, and stock prices fell.* ([TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/spook))

Comment: I would go with spook. :)

Answer (score 7):

You may be looking for **[panicked](http://tfd.com/panicked)**:

> To affect or be affected with panic

and **panic** defined as

> A sudden, overpowering feeling of fear, often affecting many people at once

Answer (score 4):

Consider **freeze**:

> Become suddenly motionless or paralyzed with **fear** or shock

([oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/freeze))

Another single-word alternative is **start**:

> To move suddenly because you are **afraid** or surprised by something

([Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/start_1))

Answer (score 2):

Consider, *he **shuddered***. [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/tressaillir)

> shudder: (of a a person) tremble convulsively, typically as a result of fear or revulsion. [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/shudder)

Comment: This is what I first thought of, because shuddering is more of a gut reaction, almost a biological response which indicates the onset of fear.

Answer (score 1):

The question and the sample sentence have some issues:

1. Firstly, both "frightened" and "afraid" are regarded as strong terms, and quite negative emotional / physical experiences, so why would you wish to apply this to a father being surprised by his children — wouldn't it be a fun thing?
2. Secondly, the sentence construction contains two awkward repeats ("room" and "children") and this can be readily corrected, including by using a pronoun.
3. The term "inside his room" is fairly irregular, and "in his room" is sufficient.
4. Words that might suit include startled, surprised, shocked, "given a start" (old-fashioned), "got a shock", "got a fright" (less negative than the adjectives "frightened" and "frightening") — and a couple of Americanisms (okay in certain contexts) — ambushed or blind-sided

Comment: It'd be helpful to focus on your point #4 and do more to support your suggestions there.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps **frighted**?  (As opposed to frightened the adjective.)  A bit of an obscure word, but certainly a valid one.

Comment: Hi, Stackstuck—and welcome to English Language & Usage. I like the word suggestion _frighted_ very much; but at this site, even when a question asks for nothing more than a single word that means something, we try to make the answer more self-contained and immediately meaningful to readers by supplying additional pertinent information. In this case you could make your answer more useful by adding a definition of _frighted_ from a reputable dictionary (citing the dictionary by name), to give a more precise sense of why the word makes a good choice. Please consider doing so.

Comment: @SvenYargs: Any suggestions, then (for dictionaries)?

Comment: ...No, frighted != frighten or (_precisely_) to take fright, dictionaries...Although the latter is pretty close.

Comment: Hello, again, Starstruck. Sorry I didn't see your question until now; I've been away for the past week. You can find various online versions of standard dictionaries (including, I believe, Merriam-Webster, Oxford, and Collins); or you can use a reputable print dictionary (any of the above plus American Heritage, Random House, Longman, Encarta, and various others.